# Problem with URLConnection.getOutputStream() in Android

Tags: java, android, https

I have written a simple HTTPS client in Java to POST some data to a server.  The server has a valid certificate signed by a trusted CA, so I didn't have to mess with any keystores or self-signed certificates.  Here is the code:

```
try
{
    String data = "This is a test";

    SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

    URL url = new URL("https://my.server.name");

    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 

    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    InputStream ins = conn.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String inputLine;
    String result;

    while( (inputLine = in.readLine()) != null )
        result += inputLine;

    in.close();
}
catch( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code works fine when run as part of a command line Java program, but it does not work correctly on Android (at least not in the emulator).  I have traced the problem to this line:

```
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
```

The call to `conn.getOutputStream()` seems to hang until the connection times out on the server.  It does not throw an exception.  It just waits indefinitely until the connection times out on the server, and then moves on to `wr.write(data)` but this fails, of course, because the connection is now closed.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?  I searched for issues regarding `getOutputStream()` on Android, but I did not find anything useful yet.

Thanks!

Comment: I should have mentioned that the app does have the "INTERNET" uses-permission in the manifest, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Seems to work for https://www.google.com ... Are you sure it's not a server issue? What exception gets thrown on android?

Comment: @adotout: Are you testing this under the Android emulator?  I'm seeing the same behavior with google.com, right at the call to `getOutputStream()`.  It doesn't throw an exception, it just hangs until the server times out the connection.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the Android emulator.  I installed the app on my Motorola Droid and everything works fine.  This isn't really an answer to the original problem, but the problem is irrelevant now (at least to me) since I can test the app on my phone.

Comment: @Dave: can you please answer the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the Android emulator. I installed the app on my Motorola Droid and everything works fine. This isn't really an answer to the original problem, but the problem is irrelevant now (at least to me) since I can test the app on my phone.